# Asterisk in string causes file listing?

Tags: php

Oh my good lord. I am trying to update some coding left behind by the previous programmer. The issue I'm running into is that when I try to write an SQL statement, the asterisk gets replaced by a file listing.

he previous guy liked to run PHP scripts like shell scripts. (If all you have is a hammer...) So, this is running from the command line.

```
// Here's Jason's additions. We add split comissions to the splits table and merge them with the records coming out of GP.
$jemsql = "select * from splits where salesPerson = '$salesCode'";
print "JemSQL: ".$jemsql."\n\n";
$sp_data = $mysql->query($jemsql);
$headData = array_merge($headData, $sp_data);
```

Basic PHP, right? Well, I keep getting an SQL error and the logging reveals...

```
select MJS_new.report.php OLE Spreadsheet Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer-0.9.2.tgz (long file listing...) 
from exception where salesPerson = 'JD'
```

I went back and ran his original script, and the problem is OEM. He has the same problem in the same place.

Help me out here, why is the asterisk returning a file listing? How can the asterisk get overwritten? Is there something I can do to stop this behaviour? More code if needed, but I am stumped. How does this even happen?

EDIT:
I have minimized the file, keeping only what is absolutely needed:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php
<?
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
$db_host = 'datasrv';
$db_user = 'XXXX';
$db_pass = 'XXXX';
$db_name = 'financials';
mysql_connect($GLOBALS["db_host"], $GLOBALS["db_user"], $GLOBALS["db_pass"]) or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($GLOBALS["db_name"]) or die('Could not select database'.$db);
// Here's Jason's additions. We add split comissions to the splits table and merge them with teh records coming out of GP.
$jemsql = "select * from splits where salesPerson = '".$salesCode."'";
print "JemSQL: ".$jemsql."\n\n";
$sp_data = mysql_query($jemsql)
?>
```

When I run this with the shell script that is normally used to kick it off, here's the output:

```
JemSQL: select MJS_new.report.php OLE Spreadsheet Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer-0.9.2.tgz (long file listing) from splits where salesPerson = ''
```

If I just run it from the command line:

```
/usr/local/bin/php ./min_report.php JD test.pdf
JemSQL: select * from splits where salesPerson = ''
```

Here's the shell script that calls it:

```
for salesPerson in ${sales[*]}; do
    fileTarget="$mountTarget$salesPerson/$fileName";
    dirTarget="$mountTarget$salesPerson/";
    out=`/usr/local/bin/php ./min_report.php $salesPerson $fileTarget`
    echo $out;
    out=`cp reports/$salesPerson.xls $dirTarget`;
    echo $out;
    echo $salesPerson;
    cnt=`expr $cnt + 1`
done
```

So, at least I'm clued in to the problem... And I'm quite curious to know why he chose that "echo" method of running a command in the bash shell.

Comment: there is no way that a `*` embedded in a php string would ever get expanded to a file listing, unless somehow you run this entire script as directly input in a unix shell, and even then `foo="bar *"` in a bash script will not expand `*`, because it's inside a string. Besides, your $jemsql isn't ANYTHING like the query in your error log.

Comment: `echo '*';` does the same thing?

Comment: Yes, `echo "*\n\n"` also gives me a file listing. Weird. 

Marc B - I've been doing this for years, and up until today I would have said the same thing. The logging (I just realized) is from running his "old" code. The SQL is the same, we're just calling different tables. The problem still remains that the asterisk is getting turned into a list of files and folders in the directory.

Comment: And if you run the same script in the normal way...aka prefered web browser?

Comment: Robert, the script doesn't run in a web browser. I would have to do some modifications to get it to accept it's vars as POST or GET as opposed to ARGV. Then there's no output.

FYI, I have also tried this with single quotes so it doesn't interpolate. Still the same result. I am stumped.

Comment: some where there is a string replace going on